# Wine Cannot Load the Necessary Libraries in a Google Colab Instance

Tags: unix, google-colaboratory, wine

I have a notebook in Google Colab I am trying to use run a windows program, but I always get the same library error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
```

I have tried to `!find libtcmalloc.so.4 libtcmalloc-minimal4` but never seem to locate the library I need anywhere on the system. I had assumed that `libtmalloc` was installed with `libgoogle-perftools-dev` but I guess not?

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Comment: Show your google colab notebook